# Indexing multidimensional arrays with argmin indices applied along one axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have two multidimensional array, let's say x and y both of them with 5 dimensions and I would like to find the value of x at which the last component of y is minima. 
To find the indexes I just use `I=argmin(y,axis=-1)` and this returns me a 4-dimensional array of indexes. How should I do to find the values of x for those indexes? Some sort of `x[I]`?

Comment: 2 D...4 D ?  Provide some code and some research so we can have an idea about what you are talking about

Comment: what I do have is a x array of shape `In[87] shape(x)
Out[87]: (6, 10, 10, 5, 50)`
and a y array of the same dimensions. What I would like to find are the values of x for which the last dimension of y is minimized. 
The first step I do is `I=argmin(y, axis=-1)` which returns me an array of indexes. Now I would like to know how to check which x correspond for those indexes

Comment: @gian9 Can you provide x and y example, as well as desired output?

Comment: @Nuageux Might be tough to produce for a `5D` data. I guess one can assume random data with a random shaped `5D` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** That's basically [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) extended to `5D` case. To make things a bit more convenient, we can make use of open range arrays with [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) and then perform the `advanced-indexing`, like so -

```
d0,d1,d2,d3,d4 = x.shape
s0,s1,s2,s3 = np.ogrid[:d0,:d1,:d2,:d3]
ymin = y[s0,s1,s2,s3,I]
xmin = x[s0,s1,s2,s3,I]
```

**Approach #2 :** We can shorten it a bit, by merging the first two steps with [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) and thus have a generic function to handle ndarrays of generic number of dimensions -

```
indxs = np.ix_(*[np.arange(i) for i in x.shape[:-1]]) + (I,)
ymin = y[indxs]
xmin = x[indxs]
```

Let's use some sample random valued array and verify by directly computing the `min` along last axis with `y.min(axis=-1)` i.e. `y.min(-1)` and comparing it against the indexed value `ymin` from the proposed codes -

```
In [117]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,4,5,6,7))
     ...: y = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,4,5,6,7))
     ...: I = np.argmin(y,axis=-1)
     ...: 

In [118]: d0,d1,d2,d3,d4 = x.shape
     ...: s0,s1,s2,s3 = np.ogrid[:d0,:d1,:d2,:d3]
     ...: ymin = y[s0,s1,s2,s3,I]
     ...: xmin = x[s0,s1,s2,s3,I]
     ...: 

In [119]: np.allclose( y.min(-1), ymin)
Out[119]: True

In [120]: indxs = np.ix_(*[np.arange(i) for i in x.shape[:-1]]) + (I,)
     ...: ymin = y[indxs]
     ...: xmin = x[indxs]
     ...: 

In [121]: np.allclose( y.min(-1), ymin)
Out[121]: True
```

Comment: But with this process the dimension are not kept, am I wrong? It would be preferable to keep dimension such that to easily handle the arrays

Comment: @gian9 To keep dims, you can append a new-axis at the end :`ymin[...,None]` and `xmin[...,None]`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `argmin` with a 1 or 2d array is fairly simple, but with 3 or more, the mapping is harder to understand:

```
In [332]: y=np.arange(24)
In [333]: np.random.shuffle(y)
In [334]: y=y.reshape(2,3,4)
In [335]: y
Out[335]: 
array([[[19, 12,  9, 21],
        [ 8, 13, 20, 17],
        [22, 11,  5,  1]],

       [[ 7,  2, 23, 16],
        [ 0, 10,  6,  4],
        [14, 18, 15,  3]]])

In [338]: I = np.argmin(y, axis=-1)
In [339]: I
Out[339]: 
array([[2, 0, 3],
       [1, 0, 3]], dtype=int32)
In [340]: np.min(y, axis=-1)
Out[340]: 
array([[9, 8, 1],
       [2, 0, 3]])
```

The result is (2,3), one index for each plane/row.

The `I[0,0]` means that `y[i,j,I[i,j]]` is the minimum in the `i,j` row.

So we need a way to generate that `i,j` pairing

```
In [345]: i,j = np.ix_(np.arange(2), np.arange(3))
In [346]: i
Out[346]: 
array([[0],
       [1]])
In [347]: j
Out[347]: array([[0, 1, 2]])

In [349]: y[i,j,I[i,j]]
Out[349]: 
array([[9, 8, 1],
       [2, 0, 3]])
```

Or shorten that to:

```
In [350]: y[i,j,I]
Out[350]: 
array([[9, 8, 1],
       [2, 0, 3]])
```

---

Even with 2d the method is the same:

```
In [360]: z=y[:,:,1]
In [361]: z
Out[361]: 
array([[12, 13, 11],
       [ 2, 10, 18]])
In [362]: idx=np.argmin(z, axis=-1)
In [363]: idx
Out[363]: array([2, 0], dtype=int32)
In [364]: z[[0,1], idx]       # index the 1st dim with range
Out[364]: array([11,  2])
```

---

Using `mgrid` might make it easier to visualize the process:

```
In [378]: i,j =np.mgrid[0:2,0:3]
In [379]: i
Out[379]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
In [380]: j
Out[380]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
In [381]: y[i, j, I]
Out[381]: 
array([[9, 8, 1],
       [2, 0, 3]])
```

here `i` and `j` are (2,3) arrays that match `I` in shape.  Together the 3 arrays select a (2,3) array of elements from `y`.

`ix_` and `ogrid` just generate the equivalent `open` arrays.